# PHP string comparison when string ending can contain random numbers

Tags: php

I need to make the PHP below work.  I basically need to take a string stored in `$sshCommandResponseString` and check to see if it contains 1 of 4 possibble strings.

```
start: Job is already running: mysql
mysql start/running, process 8019
mysql stop/waiting mysql start/running, process 8348
stop: Unknown instance: mysql start/running, process 8693
```

The last 3 string end with a 4 digit number which will always be a different value.  So I cannot do a simple if/else check like the function below does as the string will sometimes end with a 4 digit number!

So what is the best way to check to see if my string matches 1 of these 4 strings?

```
function didMySqlDbRestart($sshCommandResponseString){

    if( $sshCommandResponseString == 'start: Job is already running: mysql' ){
        return true;
    }else if( $sshCommandResponseString == 'mysql start/running, process 8019' ){
        return true;
    }else if( $sshCommandResponseString == 'mysql stop/waiting mysql start/running, process 8348' ){
        return true;
    }else if( $sshCommandResponseString == 'stop: Unknown instance: mysql start/running, process 8693' ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

if(didMySqlDbRestart($sshCommandResponseString)){
    echo 'SUCCESS: MySQL Database Rebooted';
}else{
    echo 'ERROR: MySQL Database Did Not Reboot';
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Adding on to user Laser's answer perhaps something like this would be ok...

```
  function didMySqlDbRestart($sshCommandResponseString){
    if(preg_match('/^.*\d{4}$/', trim($sshCommandResponseString)) > 0){
        return true;
    }else if($sshCommandResponseString == 'start: Job is already running: mysql'){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Assign these 4 string to an array (so that it's dynamic nature will not affect) and do a foreach to compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking regex here.

```
<?php
  function didMySqlDbRestart($sshCommandResponseString){
    return preg_match('/process \d+$/', trim($sshCommandResponseString)) > 0;
  }

 if(didMySqlDbRestart($sshCommandResponseString)){
    echo 'SUCCESS: MySQL Database Rebooted';
    } else{
   echo 'ERROR: MySQL Database Did Not Reboot';
 }
```

Comment: `^.*` in your regex is unnecessary, you also don't handle 1st case and generally just test for number at the end of the string

Comment: @Laser see my updated question at the bottom, I used your code but modified to address the issues pwolaq mentioned.  If you want to do something like that in your answer.

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning.  The 3 strings ending with random numbers are always prefixed with `process` before the numbers like this `process 8019` so perhaps the regex could also look for that word before the numbers?

Comment: @JasonDavis using a regex when all you want to know is whether the string contains the substring "process" is very pointless. Just use strpos for that. It's faster and more readable.

Comment: @Gordon It's not just the string `process` but also followed by a 4 digit bumber and only 3 of 4 possibble match strings end with that as the first does not contain the number or string `process`

Comment: @Gordon, you 're right but regex is more powerful in these situations

Comment: @JasonDavis yes, so you can reliably strpos for "process" and will know that mysql has restarted, which is faster than regexing for the digits you are not interested in anyway. Likewise, you could just strpos for the fixed first string that doesn't contain the PID. Since you are apparently only interested in knowing whether MySql did or did not reboot.

Comment: @Laser regex are more powerful but also much slower than a simple strpos. And in this particular situation, their power is unneeded.

Comment: You 're right @Gordon but he want PID prefixed by "process" and the PID is not always the same. You can do that with strpos but it's way too much code than regex

Comment: @Laser thanks.  1 issue I have now.  I just realized it is not always 4 numbers long sometimes it is more.  Can you adjust for any length number? thanks

Comment: @JasonDavis Good thought. Nice. I was actually thinking about the fact that PIDs can be of variable length. So you could do '/process \d+$/'.

Answer (score 4):

use `strpos` to check for the constant part of the string or use `preg_match` to test it with regular expression